# Angular Js in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, angularjs

Can anyone tell me how to convert the below angular js code to visualforce ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        body     { padding-top:30px; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="container">

    <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
    <div class="page-header"><h1>AngularJS Form Validation</h1></div>

    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <!-- FORM ============================================================== -->
    <!-- =================================================================== -->

    <!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
            <label>Name*</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required>
            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine }">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8">
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
            <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScriptFile:app.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        body     { padding-top:30px; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="container">

    <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
    <div class="page-header"><h1>AngularJS Form Validation</h1></div>

    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <!-- FORM ============================================================== -->
    <!-- =================================================================== -->

    <!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
            <label>Name*</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required>
            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine }">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8">
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
            <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>

    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <!-- VALIDATION TABLES ================================================= -->
    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <div class="page-header"><h1>Validation Tables</h1></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Form</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.$valid, danger: userForm.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.$pristine, danger: !userForm.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Name</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.name.$valid, danger: userForm.name.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.name.$pristine, danger: !userForm.name.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.name.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Username</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.username.$valid, danger: userForm.username.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.username.$pristine, danger: !userForm.username.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.username.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Email</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.email.$valid, danger: userForm.email.$invalid }">Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.email.$pristine, danger: !userForm.email.$pristine }">Pristine</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-class="{ success: userForm.email.$dirty }">Dirty</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have converted the above code:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false">

<html>
<head>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        body     { padding-top:30px; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>


    <script>
        // create angular app
    var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);

    // create angular controller
    validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

        // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
        $scope.submitForm = function() {

            // check to make sure the form is completely valid
            if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
                alert('our form is amazing');
            }

        };

    });

    </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="container">

    <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
    <div class="page-header"><h1>AngularJS Form Validation</h1></div>

    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <!-- FORM ============================================================== -->
    <!-- =================================================================== -->

    <!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate="novalidate">

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
            <label>Name*</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required="true"/>
            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine }">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8"/>
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" required="required"/>
            <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
            <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>

        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

</apex:page>
```

But It doesnt work properly. I don't know what the problem is in my code, any ideas?

Please help!

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. It seems like it could be a repeat of your [other question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54592/angularjs-form-in-visualforce-page). Try updating your answer to clearly state what is not working, what you expect to happen and an errors that are been thrown.

Answer (score 4):

This line won't do anything:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Where is your app.js file stored? In a static resource? You will need to upload your js file into a static resource and reference it using $Resource and URLFOR syntax (if it is in a zip file).

I believe that you will also have to reference an SSL enabled CDN for Angular if you're not also going to store it in a static resource, so you tag would look like this:

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
```

Optimally though, you would also move any JS dependencies into your own static resource.

[Referencing a Static Resource in Visualforce Markup](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources_reference.htm)